# Add element to Array by converting Array to List, adding the element and converting it back again

Tags: java, arrays, list

I need to add en int element to an array.

I thought about convering the array to an arrayList, addind the int and then converting the arrayList into an array again.

As expected, I failed completely.

aGrades is an array, lGrades is an ArrayList

```
// add one grade from 1-5
    public void enter (int grade){
    ArrayList<Integer> lGrades = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(aGrades));
    lGrades.add(grade);
    aGrades = listArray.toArray(lGrades);
  }
```

The error right now is:

```
Histo.java:28: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(List<int[]>)
    ArrayList<Integer> lGrades = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(aGrades));
                                 ^
constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Integer>) is not applicable
  (actual argument List<int[]> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Integer> by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayList.ArrayList() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
  (actual argument List<int[]> cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
Histo.java:30: error: incompatible types
    aGrades = lGrades.toArray(new Integer[lGrades.size()]);
                             ^
  required: int[]
  found:    Integer[]
```

This is probably a complete mess, but I have searched through many threads about this and am very confused by now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need to change the size of the array, maybe best if you stick with ArrayList.

Comment: What failed? Do you get any errors? If so post them. If not, what happened and what do instead expect to happen?

Comment: It fails because he is using primitives in the array. toArray() only works with objects.

Comment: Essentially, you have two choices, and the answers include sample code for each of them. If adding an element is frequent, switch to ArrayList<Integer>. If it is rare, consider creating a new array one element longer, copying in the old data, and assigning the new element at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    aGrades = Arrays.copyOf(aGrades, aGrades.length + 1);
    aGrades[aGrades.length - 1] = grade;
```

Comment: this is actually surprisingly simple

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is a compile-time error, it's at the following line:

```
aGrades = listArray.toArray(lGrades);
```

Simply replace with:

```
aGrades = lGrades.toArray(new Integer[lGrades.size()]);
```

Although I would recommend just using a `List<Integer>` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add elements to your array, you are probably better off just using and `ArrayList` instead of converting back and forth. If for some reason you don't want to do that though, a more efficient way to lengthen your array would be something like this:

```
int [] newAGrades = new int[aGrades.length + 1];

System.arraycopy(aGrades, 0, newAGrades, 0, aGrades.length);

newAGrades[aGrades.length] = grade;

aGrades = newAGrades;
```

Although, again, just using an `ArrayList` would be a far better idea:

```
aGrades.add(grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, your best bet is to use an ArrayList with Integer objects. If you want to stick with an array of int primitives, you'd be better off managing the resizing yourself with the arrays.

```
  // add one grade from 1-5
  public void enter (int grade){
    int[] aGradesTmp = new int[aGrades.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(aGrades, 0, aGradesTmp, 0, aGrades.length);
    aGradesTmp[aGrades.length] = grade;
    aGrades = aGradesTmp;
  }
```

What you are doing above is memory and processor inefficient. This workaround is memory inefficient, but more efficient on the processor since System.arraycopy() is implemented as a native method.

Ultimately you just want to stay away from arrays whenever you can and just use the collection classes.